# how to align text and image verticle middle in div

Tags: javascript, css

How can i align text and image verticle align middle ??

jsfiddle demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/j3wDP/

My CSS:

```
.rating{
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
}
span img{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px 3px; 
}
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="rating">Rating <span><img src="like.jpg">233<img src="dislike.jpg">100</span></div>  
</body
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some property

```
span img{  vertical-align:middle;}
```

See [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/j3wDP/2/)

Comment: :P :P dont know why i didnt thought about this :) anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j3wDP/3/)

```
.rating{
    border: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 180px;
line-height:50px;
    height: 50px;
}
span img{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px 3px; 
}
```

You can use `line-height`

Answer (score 0):

Change your css like this

```
.rating{
    border: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height:20px;
}
span img{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px 3px; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use Line-height or us can use

`.rating{
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
}`

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions. You can wrap your content into two (e.g. div-)containers and handle them like a table. Something like that:

```
<div style="display:table; height: 200px; background:red;">
    <div style="display:table-cell; height:200px; vertical-align:middle">
        <span>Your Content</span>
    </div>
</div>​
```

it's important to give them a height property and use display: table and display:table-cell instead of it. another way is to center this span with position: absolute:

```
<div style="height:200px; background:red; position:relative">
    <span style="height:20px; position:absolute; top:50%; margin-top:-10px;">Your content</span>
</div>​
```

In that example the margin-top value is calculated by the half value of the height (height: 20px = margin-top:-10px). But I would prefer the first way.